# Correct way to make a custom block theme responsive

Tags: theme-development, themes, block-editor, responsive, full-site-editing

I am trying to make a custom responsive theme using the new Block / FSE approach however I dont think the method Im using is correct.

This is the current design:

[image: Wordpress Custom Theme Site Top]

This is the view in block editor:

[image: Site Top in Editor]

In order for this site to be mobile first / responsive the cover image and site logo need to dynamically resize based on viewport size

So far my approach has been to use additional CSS and create a class to apply height: auto and width: 35vw

[image: Additional CSS]

However the issue I see with this approach is that within the block editor there are controls for image width with use non-responsive units of px

[image: Image width control]

Of course the additional CSS overrides this but that seems to defeat the point of the block editor